# How to make ng-repeat update view on condition only

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Say I have an `ng-repeat` directive and it displays some data in the table.
When I press a button I send the `$http` API call to the server and it responds with the new data which is displayed in the same table with a little delay.
I would like `ng-repeat` to re-render the table view only after this new data has finished loading. But as of now I can see how `ng-repeat` shows an empty table for a moment and only after that the new data is fetched.

So the question is how does one make Angular update the ng-repeat only on a condition? The event that is fired when the data has finished loading can be an example of such condition.

P. S. I tried prefixing my array with `::`, but of no help. It prevented Angular from instant updating the view, but I don't know the way to force the update when I want to.

Comment: This seems like an issue with the order of operations between your controller and your API call.  Without seeing any code, it *sounds like* your controller or API is clearing your array to prepare it for new data before the `$http` promise has returned.

Comment: also `::` is the **bind once** syntax, so if you have used it, then your repeat should *never* update, unless you are completely replacing the array, which reinforces what I was saying in my first comment.  Bottom line, we need to see some code to help with a good solution here.

Comment: In other words...show us the code